# Can I include "AND" , "OR" operators in java search eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I need to know if I can include and or operators to search eg create* or put* in a java search in eclipse

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the 'Java Search' tab of the 'Search' dialog, you can only specify a single search pattern. There are no and / or operations. The only special characters are '*' to match anything and '?' to match a single character.

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was a smarter way to make searches in eclipse.